# Conditional statements on comparing elements of three unequal length vectors in R

Tags: r, date, if-statement, vector

I am having a pretty interesting problem related to computer's logical thinking in R that I would love to hear your inputs on whether my understanding is correct. Let's say I have 3 vectors `A`, `B`, `C` of date-type strings in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` (e.g. `2021-01-01`, `2021-12-31`). Assume `length(A) = length(B)`, but `length(C)` is at least ten-times larger, and all the elements in each vector `A`, `B` and `C` are in increasing order.

**Objective.** I need to write an `IF()` statement to check if **any** elements chosen from vector `A` is less than **some** elements in vector `C`, and if any element from vector `B` is greater than **some** elements in vector `C` (if Yes, I would do something). Can someone please help shed the light on whether the two `IF` statements below are equivalent and indeed they helped me achieve this goal?

**My attempt.**

I initially tried this statement, but it did not quite work due to the unequal length of `A`, `B` vs `C`

```
if(any(A <= C & C <= B) { 
       do something here
}
```

After thinking for a while, I somehow think the above statement is equivalent to the following:

```
if(A <= max(C) & min(C) <= B){ 
      do something here
}
```

Comment: Hi! What do you mean with "at least ten times larger"? Does it mean that `C` contains 10 dates?

Comment: it means `length(C)` >= `10*length(A)`

Comment: Ok, but when you compare `A <=max(C)` you want to see if all the dates in A are earlier than all the dates in B. Am I right? And the same thing for the second expression `C<=B). Is that right?

Comment: No, I only want to see if a specific date in A is less than *some* dates in C? In other words, I am trying to write an equivalent statement to the `if(any(...))`

Comment: What I meant was: basically, for any fixed value of index `i` in vector `A` and `B`, write the `IF` statement that is equivalent to TEST whether there is some elements in C that satisfies the condition `A[i] =< C & B[i] >= C`

Answer (score 1):

An `if` statement must operate on a length-1 logical test. If you have anything like `A <= max(C)` then you are operating on a logical *vector* the same length as `A`.

If you want to find out if *any* `A` is less than *any* `C`, and *any* `B` is greater than *any* `C` you could do:

```r
if(min(A) < max(C) && min(C) < max(B))
```

Which is of course a length-one logical test.

Comment: Thank you very much. In this case, I only want to write the equivalent statement to `if(any(A[i] =< C & B[i] >= C)` without having to use the `for` loop around index `i` (so, basically, for any fixed value of `i`, test if there is *some* elements in C that satisfies the condition `A[i] =< C & B[i] >= C`)

Comment: @user177196 then what's wrong with `if(A[i] < max(C) && min(C) < B[i])`?

Comment: If you want a vectorised form, then you could use `ifelse`- `ifelse(A < max(C) & min(C) < B, "Yes", "No")`

Comment: `if(A[i] < max(C) && min(C) < B[i])` forces me to do the `for` loop, but I want to avoid that to speed up the runtime. `Ifelse` won't let me do a massive thing inside the `TRUE` part, no?

Comment: But if you need to do a massive thing inside the `TRUE` part, and you want to do it for every `TRUE` element of the vector, then by definition you need to run the massive thing several times - unless it can take a vectorised input, in which case you can simply use the logical vector `A < max(C) & min(C) < B` . Perhaps an edit to include a more expanded view of what you are trying to achieve will help?

Comment: you were spot-on. The things inside involving `clusterMap()` so it can handle vectorized inputs. Are you familiar with `clusterEvalQ()` and `clusterExport()` as I have experienced huge setbacks in loading all the entire library, source files and variables into all the clusters?